# Driver Development (Windows) : What is RTL?

Tags: c, windows, kernel, kmdf

Can someone explain me please what is RTL in the context of driver development for Windows ?

Development Tool : Visual studio 2019
Driver Type: Kernel Mode (kmdf).
Programming Language : C.

Comment: Right to left layout

Comment: It’s not an HTML terminology?

Comment: Again learned something :)

Comment: @MaximilianFixl I glad to hear that you have learned something new! :).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Many kernel API functions start with the **Rtl** prefix - that's an abbreviation of Run Time Library.